# Get the absolute path of the currently edited file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-api

I'd like to write a plugin that does something with the currently edited file in Eclipse. But I'm not sure how to properly get the file's full path.

This is what I do now:

```
IFile file = (IFile) window.getActivePage().getActiveEditor.getEditorInput().
    getAdapter(IFile.class);
```

Now I have an IFile object, and I can retrieve it's path:

```
file.getFullPath().toOSString();
```

However this still only gives me the path relative to the workspace. How can I get the absolute path from that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looks like you want [`IResource.getRawLocation()`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIResource.html).  That returns an `IPath`, which also has a `makeAbsolute()` method if you want to be doubly sure you've got an absolute path.

Comment: The link from IResource.getRawLocation() has been changed now.

Answer (score 6):

I think a more Java friendly solution would be to do use the following:

```
IResource.getLocation().toFile()
```

This takes advantage of the IPath API (the getLocation() part) and will return a java.io.File instance. Of course the other answers will probably get you to where you want to be too.

On a tangential note, I find the IDE class `(org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE)` a useful utility resource when it comes to editors.

Answer (score 5):

The answer that worked for me (and I tested it!) was:

```
// Get the currently selected file from the editor
IWorkbenchPart workbenchPart = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActivePart(); 
IFile file = (IFile) workbenchPart.getSite().getPage().getActiveEditor().getEditorInput().getAdapter(IFile.class);
if (file == null) throw new FileNotFoundException();
String path = file.getRawLocation().toOSString();
System.out.println("path: " + path);
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually call IFile.getLocation() which returns an IPath and then call IPath.toOSString().

```
file.getLocation().toOSString()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IWorkspace ws      = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();  
IProject   project = ws.getRoot().getProject("*project_name*");

IPath location = new Path(editor.getTitleToolTip());  
IFile file     = project.getFile(location.lastSegment());

into file.getLocationURI() it's the absolute path
```

Answer (score -2):

For me, this run ok.

IWorkspaceRoot workSpaceRoot = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();

File file = workSpaceRoot.getRawLocation().makeAbsolute().toFile();

file list from this location:

File[] files = file.listFiles();