# Get abs path from the currently edited file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have the same problem as the guy in this post:
[Get the absolute path of the currently edited file in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299619/get-the-absolute-path-of-the-currently-edited-file-in-eclipse)

but I dont understand how to do it. In the post they say that I should use IResource.getRawLocation() but how to I get the IResource from the current file that I am viewing?

```
IFile file2 = (IFile)workBench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor().getEditorInput().getAdapter(IFile.class);

IPath path = file2.getRawLocation().makeAbsolute();
String ss = path.toString();

System.out.println(ss);
```

But this will still not give me the right path to the linked file, I get something like:
/path/to/plugin/path/to/relative/path/to/file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An IFile is-an IResource.  You don't need to get one from another.  Just call `file2.getRawLocation()`.  If that's not working it's not because it's not an IResource.

Is the file in a jar/zip/any archive file?  If so, it looks like that could be the correct absolute path.